# Repetition of named entity in coreference resolution

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, coreference-resolution

I am trying to find coreferences for the following text, using neuralcoref:

Alan and Bruder are great friends with Chris and Donald. Alan and Bruder want to head to Lebanon while Chris and Donald wish to stay in United States. Chris and Donald have not made up their mind yet, but will get there soon. Alan and Bruder do not want to separate but there seems to be no choice.

**Code:**

```
case_a_bi = 'Alan and Bruder are great friends with Chris and Donald. Alan 
and Bruder want to head to Lebanon while Chris and Donald wish to stay in 
United States. Chris and Donald have not made up their mind yet, but will 
get there soon. Alan and Bruder do not want to separate but there seems to 
be no choice.'
nlp = spacy.load('en')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
case_a_bi = unidecode(case_a_bi)
doc = nlp(case_a_bi)
doc._.coref_clusters
doc._.coref_resolved
```

**Output for coref clusters:**

```
[Alan and Bruder: [Alan and Bruder, Alan, Alan and Bruder, Alan, Alan and Bruder],

Chris: [Chris, Chris, Chris],

Chris and Donald: [Chris and Donald, Chris and Donald, Chris and Donald, their],

Donald: [Donald, Donald, Donald]]
```

**Output for coref resolution:**

Alan and Bruder are great friends with Chris and Donald. Alan and Bruder want to head to Lebanon while Chris and Donald Donald wish to stay in United States. **Chris and Donald Donald** have not made up Chris and Donald mind yet, but will get there soon. Alan and Bruder do not want to separate but there seems to be no choice.

As per the outputs mentioned, I get correct clusters for Chris and Donald, but when I try to resolve these coreferences, Donald gets repeated twice in the result.

Can someone help me in understanding what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as image.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I have added the code.